# Docker compose with image and build both specified in a single service bug?

Tags: docker, image, docker-compose, build

I have understood that if I have in a directory the following

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM fedora
ENV VAR=42
CMD ["bash"]
```

And the following compose file

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: ubuntu
```

Docker should build an image from `fedora` and name it `ubuntu`. But instead it seems it just pulls the ubuntu image (if I comment out `image: ubuntu` it pulls the fedora image). Why is that?

> [docker
> docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/):
> If the image does not exist, Compose attempts to pull it, unless you
> have also specified build, in which case it builds it using the
> specified options and tags it with the specified tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested and it worked for me, but I did need to change the compose file contents to make the service a map, as yours is typed I got: "services.build must be a mapping".

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  so_test:
    build: .
    image: ubuntu
```

But my Dockerfile was the same:

```
FROM fedora
ENV VAR=42
CMD ["bash"]
```

Build logs:

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ so_test Pulled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9.3s
   ⠿ 5f3d23ccb99f Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                  3.8s
[+] Building 8.0s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 72B                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/fedora:latest                                                                                                                                                                                 1.3s
 => [auth] library/fedora:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/fedora@sha256:40ba585f0e25c096a08c30ab2f70ef3820b8ea5a4bdd16da0edbfc0a6952fa57                                                                                                                                  6.6s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/fedora@sha256:40ba585f0e25c096a08c30ab2f70ef3820b8ea5a4bdd16da0edbfc0a6952fa57                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => sha256:cfe295ee216d5995136f055659294ebc2dcbd736f94c5ac14dffb39fa2eebb27 529B / 529B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => sha256:788739295edac7b7b34351db644c8a5506e7de56af398985c59bae8d87d45a1e 2.00kB / 2.00kB                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => sha256:3f28ea9d8c33c40fa95a05f63764cc6e8ef9d9449fd75da415eca42543b80f52 53.62MB / 53.62MB                                                                                                                                                 4.8s
 => => sha256:40ba585f0e25c096a08c30ab2f70ef3820b8ea5a4bdd16da0edbfc0a6952fa57 1.20kB / 1.20kB                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:3f28ea9d8c33c40fa95a05f63764cc6e8ef9d9449fd75da415eca42543b80f52                                                                                                                                                        1.6s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:f5f920b43d06c51352da33d13114986564abdfb5ce7e9583d97a414b3e17654a                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/ubuntu
```

[Screenshot of Docker Desktop container image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnmNa.png)

I was curious to try this because I didn't understand the wording from the Docker docs at first, but made sense after.

Comment: Very interesting. Did you have an ubuntu (the real distribution) image before running `docker compose up`? I replicated your results by deleting all my images (including the real ubuntu one) and running the compose step. It seems there definitely is some aliasing with image names. If I did `docker run --rm -it ubuntu` before running docker compose it downloads an `ubuntu` image and then in the `docker-compose` step it uses that (as it probably sees it exists) instead of building it from the `Dockerfile`, therefore running an ubuntu container instead of (building and running) a fedora one.

Comment: Just now tested it that way, running/downloading the Ubuntu image before running the compose and got those results as well; the stack was created with the Ubuntu image instead of building and naming the Fedora image to Ubuntu. I did not have any images locally when doing my original run. Interesting thing it seems you've identified.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Reading the docs one has to interpret **if it exists** as if the **image name exists** (not the actual contents), which makes sense as probably docker uses that as the identifier.